# WCF HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler

Tags: wcf

I have made various attempts to resolve 404.17 issue for WCF but none of them worked

Development Environment VS 2008 Team System, .NET Framework 3.5, OS Windows 7.0, IIS Application pool v2.0 classic.

I installed C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ ServiceModelReg

I enabled Windows Communication HTTP Activation using Turn windows feature on

Handler Mappings in IIS

svc-ISAPI-2.0          *.svc Enabled Unspecified IsapiModule inherited
svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit    *.svc Enabled Unspecified IsapiModule inherited
svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit    *.svc Enabled Unspecified IsapiModule inherited

I cannot change the AppPool to integrated mode becuase Application does not work without classic mode, I have asmx webservices and they all are accessible. Its  WCF which is causing issue. Could anyone help me how to resolve this 404.17 issue

```
<system.serviceModel>
                         <behaviors>
                             <serviceBehaviors>
                                 <behavior name="Solution1.WebApp.CallMonitorServiceBehavior">
                                     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                                     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                                 </behavior>
                                 <behavior name="Solution1.WebApp.Service1Behavior">
                                     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                                     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                                 </behavior>
                             </serviceBehaviors>
                         </behaviors>
                         <services>
                             <service behaviorConfiguration="Solution1.WebApp.CallMonitorServiceBehavior"
                                 name="Solution1.WebApp.CallMonitorService">
                                 <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Solution1.WebApp.ICallMonitorService">
                                     <identity>
                                         <dns value="localhost" />
                                     </identity>
                                 </endpoint>
                                 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                             </service>
                             <service behaviorConfiguration="Solution1.WebApp.Service1Behavior"
                                 name="Solution1.WebApp.Service1">
                                 <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Solution1.WebApp.IService1">
                                     <identity>
                                         <dns value="localhost" />
                                     </identity>
                                 </endpoint>
                                 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                             </service>
                         </services>
                     </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try activating WCF service from windows Features. Goto "Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features" and click "Turn Windows features on or off" and check wcf services as shown in pic attached.

[image]

Comment: In the question it says WCF HTTP Activation is already enabled, do other services need to be enabled as well for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to register WCF to IIS

Navigate to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation"

and execute

```
 servicemodelreg -i
```

to install them