# Wen browse a .SVC HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-10

Hi when I browse WCF service from IIS 10 in windows 10 machine I have the below issue.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script not served by static file handler on IIS7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762287/script-not-served-by-static-file-handler-on-iis7-5)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046854/wcf-http-error-404-17-not-found-the-requested-content-appears-to-be-script-and and https://stackoverflow.com/q/25532110/578411

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could firstly check you have install the right WCF extension on your server.

You could open the server manager and select Add Role or Feature to open the Wizard.

[image]

If you have already install the WCF extension, I suggest you could check your application's web.config file to make sure you have used the right WCF setting.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService">

        <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

        <!-- The mex endpoint is explosed at http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```